# How to using ffmpeg overlay logo on video in android app while downloading?

Tags: android, image, video, overlay

I tried following the tutorial for [FFmpeg Android Java](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) and [ffmpeg4android](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html)

But even the dependency is not resolved.Please help how to easily integrate ffmpeg in android studio for overlaying image on video.

Comment: did you checked my code

Comment: Jus wanted to ask how can we use png instead of logo path in the command??

Comment: then accept the answer

Comment: String[] cmdd = {"-i", "" + file1.getAbsolutePath(), "-i", "" +"ic_launcher.png" , "-filter_complex", "overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10", outputDirectory.getPath()}; This results in failure. How to overlay drawable image on video ? Please help.

Comment: put  image in asset folder then take it from there

Comment: I have added aar file for using this library.It has increased my apk size tremendously.How to reduce size ?? Please help.

Comment: Please just ask as another question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this i used this worked for me:

```
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler;
```

import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpeg;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.LoadBinaryResponseHandler;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.exceptions.FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException;
import com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.exceptions.FFmpegNotSupportedException;

```
public class Home extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = Home.class.getSimpleName();

FFmpeg ffmpeg;
File imageFile;
File f;
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Your_directory/");
File outputDirectory;
@Bind(R.id.command)
EditText commandEditText;
@Bind(R.id.command_output)
LinearLayout outputLayout;
String paths = "";
String path2 = "";
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String fileName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    isStoragePermissionGranted();
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("name") != null) {
        fileName = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        outputDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Your_dir/" + fileName + ".mp4");
    } else {
        outputDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Your_dir/test" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");

    }

    commandEditText.setEnabled(false);

    paths = "path of video";


    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(this);
    loadFFMpegBinary();
    initUI();


    if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
        myDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/your_dir/trial.mp3");
    if (!f.exists()) try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("trial.mp3");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/your_path/newlogo.png");
    if (!imageFile.exists()) try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("newlogo.png");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();


        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    //video watermark
    String[] cmdd = {"-i", "" + paths, "-i", "" + imageFile.getPath(), "-filter_complex", "overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10", outputDirectory.getPath()};
    String[] command = cmdd;
    execFFmpegBinary(command);
}
private void loadFFMpegBinary() {
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure() {
                showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        showUnsupportedExceptionDialog();
    }
}
 private void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String s) {
                addTextViewToLayout("FAILED with output : " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                addTextViewToLayout("SUCCESS with output : " + s);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(outputDirectory.getPath()));
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(outputDirectory.getPath()), "video/mp4");
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                addTextViewToLayout("progress : " + s);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing\n" + s);
                //  Log.d(TAG, "progress still : ffmpeg " + progressDialog.getProgress());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                outputLayout.removeAllViews();
                Log.d(TAG, "Started command : ffmpeg " + command);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished command : ffmpeg " + command);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(Home.this,
                        new String[]{outputDirectory.toString()}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                //      Toast.makeText(Home.this,path+""+uri,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // do nothing for now
    }
}
private void addTextViewToLayout(String text) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(Home.this);
    textView.setText(text);
    outputLayout.addView(textView);
}

private void showUnsupportedExceptionDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Home.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .create()
            .show();

}
```

activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/background_video_color"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Home"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/command"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:minLines="3"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="start" />



<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/command_output"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</ScrollView>
```

**USE THIS IT WORK FOR ME USE FFMPEG LIBRARY ,I HAVE PROVIDED THE IMPORTS AT THE TOP** 
HERE IS THE LIBRARY
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java